# Define an extension method depending on two classes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, extension-methods

I have the following extension method defined inside `MyFragment : Fragment` class:

```
fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {
        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

I want to extract the `View.showSoftKeyboard()` extension method out of the `MyFragment : Fragment`, so I can use it in every fragment.

However, if I make this `Fragment.showSoftKeyboard()`, I have no acess to the `View` object:

```
fun Fragment.showSoftKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {
        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        // "this" won't be a View anymore, but a Fragment
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) 

    }
}
```

If I leave it as `View.showSoftKeyboard()`, I have no access to `requireActivity()`:

```
fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {

        // requireActivity() won't be accessible anymore
        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager 

        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) 
    }
}
```

Is there any way to define - from the outside - a extension method for a `View` in a `Fragment`, so I have access to both, the view object as well as  the `requireActivity()` from the `Fragment` class?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct way to do this that I know of. But you can create an interface that defines the Fragment functions you need (and that Fragment already satisfies), and tack it onto your Fragments where you want to use the extension function.

```
interface FragmentAddendum {
    fun requireActivity(): FragmentActivity

    fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
        if (requestFocus()) {
            val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }
    }
}


class MyFragment: Fragment(), FragmentAddendum {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to define - from the outside - a extension method for a View in a Fragment, so I have access to both, the view object as well as the requireActivity() from the Fragment class?

Not really. Extension functions are defined in such a way that they can be used in any **available** context. You can constraint the context in at least two ways:

- using access modifiers. Private extension functions are available only in the file they were defined;
- by declaring extension functions as members (the closes solution to the one you look for).

An example of the first mentioned way of constraining can look like: `private fun View.newFun() {}`

The second way of constraining looks like this (official Kotlin extention function example):

```
class Host(val hostname: String) {
    fun printHostname() { print(hostname) }
}

class Connection(val host: Host, val port: Int) {
     fun printPort() { print(port) }

     fun Host.printConnectionString() {
         printHostname()   // calls Host.printHostname()
         print(":")
         printPort()   // calls Connection.printPort()
     }

     fun connect() {
         /*...*/
         host.printConnectionString()   // calls the extension function
     }
}

fun main() {
    Connection(Host("kotl.in"), 443).connect()
    //Host("kotl.in").printConnectionString(443)  // error, the extension function is unavailable outside Connection
}
```

*More on [declaring extension functions as members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members).*

You can declare base class for each fragment and implement in that class `View` extension function.

Sample:

```
open class BaseFragment: Fragment() {
    fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
        if (requestFocus()) {
    
            // requireActivity() won't be accessible anymore
            val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager 
    
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) 
        }
    }
}
```

**IMHO, the better solution** is to avoid any class inheritance or interface implementation. Modify your Fragment extension function to get as an argument a `View`:

```
// Optionally set default value as getView(). Depends on your needs.
fun Fragment.showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get System service from `Context` and `Context` from `View`

```
fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Now you can extract this method from Fragment